# Laravel possible race condition?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, race-condition

I have a Laravel 5.2 backend and Angular 1 frontend application. They communicate using REST API. There is a piece of code that updates some database data on every page load (the app is a browser game, so in this case the player's resources and units are being updated/produced), but I've been running into some problems.

There are situations where the frontend requests multiple API endpoints at the same time. If a new unit has been produced since the last request, the `Entity` should be `attached()` to the `Player` model (Many-To-Many relationship). What happens in reality is that all 3 requests try to attach the new `Entity` and end up with a `SQL error: duplicate key` (not the exact wording) on the `pivot` table.

The issue is not isolated to Eloquent, for example 3 API requests at the same time result in 3 report messages being generated and so on.

What would be the best way to fix this issue? So far, I have tried wrapping the DB statements with `DB::transaction` but this did not seem to fix the issue (or I did it incorrectly).

Thank you for any helpful response.

Comment: What kind of database are you using and whats its database engine? Have in mind that traditional database engines like MySQL's MyISAM are not transactional, which means that the whole table is locked while waiting for the query to execute. If multiple requests are a common thing for your app you maybe have to consider using a transactional db engine like InnoDB.

Comment: 1. What are those "all 3 requests"? 2. How are you sending them: refreshing angular view? Refreshing page in the browser quickly? Sending them from three separate frontend instances?

Comment: @bjauy the 3 requests happen when user refreshes the page in browser. Different parts of the app loading their data pretty much.

Comment: @LePhleg I am using InnoDB already. Do you think using a `DB::transaction` is the solution? I also read something about [Laravel Pessimistic locking](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#pessimistic-locking) but I am not sure if something like this would help.

Comment: Two more things: Does the attaching needs to be done in the realtime? Is it done right after inserting the Entity, or in separate requests?

Comment: In the docs pessimistic locking seems to be used for ```select``` statements only.

Comment: Getting the SQL error about duplicate key is **just fine**, that's how it's supposed to work. When you get that error, you know the db did its job and you can catch that exception and display an error message to the user. That's the way to go about it. What you did in background task doesn't fix the problem because there is no problem to begin with. The only issue is handling errors in a nice, graceful way.

Answer (score 0):

According to [L5.2 source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.php#L946) `attach` seems to insert the record into the pivot table every time you run it.

One of the solutions could be replacing `attach` with `syncWithoutDetaching([entity_id])`.

Yet it would be even better to limit the amount of requests to single one in your angular app.

Comment: I think the `attach` error is just a symptom of Laravel executing all three attach at once which is also why 3 report messages generate and so on.
Limiting the amount of requests is also not a solution as there is nothing stopping the user from opening multiple tabs and refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I ended up creating a Laravel Command that runs forever in the background:

```
while(true) {
        updateUnitsExample();
        $this->info('Units updated for time '. date("H:m:s"));
        sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: Or you could offload update to background [queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues).